# asyncio run_until_complete does not wait that all coroutines finish

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am making my first steps in Python and I have a bit of struggle trying to understand why I do not have the expected result with this one. Here is what I am trying to achieve :

I have a function that consumes an API. While waiting for the API to answer and given that I am going through a proxy that creates additional lag, I though that sending concurrent request will speed up the process (I run 100 concurrent requests). It does. But asyncio `run_until_complete` always returns some unfinished coroutines.

Here the code (simplified):

```python
import aiohttp
import asyncio
    
async def consume_api(parameter):
    url = "someurl" #it is actually based on the parameter
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(URL, proxy="someproxy") as asyncresponse:
                r = await asyncresponse.read()
    except:
        global error_count 
        error_count += 1
        if error_count > 50:
            return "Exceeded 50 try on same request"
        else:
            return consume_api(parameter)
    return r.decode("utf-8") 

def loop_on_api(list_of_parameter):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    coroutines = [consume_api(list_of_parameter[i]) for i in range(len(list_of_parameter))]
    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coroutines))
    return results
```

When I run the debugger, the `results` returned by the `loop_on_api` function include a list of string corresponding to the results of `consume_api` and some occurence of `<coroutine objects consume_api at 0x00...>`. Those variables have a cr_running parameter at False and a cr_Frame.
Though if I check the `coroutines` variables, I can find all the 100 coroutines but none seems to have a cr_Frame.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I'm also thinking my way of counting the **50 error** will be shared by all coroutines.

Any idea how I can make it specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is coming from the proxy I am using, which sometimes do not carry the request or response. Hence forcing a rerun seems to be the best answer. Hence I now check if the results returned have some coroutines remaining and re-run the `loop_on_api()` on them

```python
def loop_on_api(list_of_parameter):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    coroutines = [consume_api(list_of_parameter[i]) for i in range(len(list_of_parameter))]
    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coroutines))

    undone = []
    rerun_list_of_parameter = []
    
    for i in range(len(results)):
        if str(type(results[i])) == "<class 'coroutine'>": #not very elegant >> is there a better way?
            undone.append(i)
            rerun_list_of_parameter.append(list_of_parameter[i])

    if len(undone) > 0:
        undone_results = loop_on_api(rerun_list_of_parameter)
        for i in range(len(undone_results)):
            results[undone[i]] = undone_results[i]

    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you can add/change/refactor what ever you want

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def consume_api(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.read()


def loop_on_api(list_of_urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    coroutines = [consume_api(url) for url in list_of_urls]

    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coroutines))
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(loop_on_api(['https://google.com', 'https://twitter.com']))
```

Comment: I don't see any difference with my code, except you removed my error management in `consume_api` (which I must keep) and expressed slightly differently how to get the parameters (which you renamed url)... But that's the exact same sequence. Can detail where is the logic update?

Comment: let's start step by step. this code works for you ?
if so, try to add your extra stuff, step by step, and each time run the program.

Comment: There's no step to take, your code is the exact same as mine, so please develop the changes because to me the whole thing is completely identical

Comment: Do you want me to copy-paste your code in the question or in the answer?

Can you share the complete code? so I can copy it and just run it? what is your list of parameters.

Comment: After carefully checking the behavior, the issue is coming from the proxies. Hence the code would behave properly (yours and mine) given that no issue would exists on the proxy side. So I can't avoid having to force rerun the faulting coroutines